# Math font in Beamer when using Lucida

Tags: beamer, math-fonts, lucida

Here's a MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lucidabr}
\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}
%\usefonttheme[stillsansseriftext,stillsansserifsmall,stillsansseriflarge,stillsansserifmath]{serif}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Test}
  123 and $123$ and $$123$$
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

`123` and `$123$` look different because one is sans serif and the other is not.  I want them to look the same.  I can achieve this using the line which is currently commented out, but it seems a bit silly to use the `serif` font theme only to switch it off again via a long list of options.  Is there a simpler, more canonical way to make both `123` and `$123$` sans serif?

(Also, do I understand the Beamer documentation correctly in that I don't have to use the `professionalfonts` theme with `lucidabr`?)

Comment: `\usepackage{mathastext}`?

Comment: If you have the commercial fonts, you can either load `unicode-math` and Lucida Math, or the 8-bit `lucimatx`.

Comment: @Davislor I have the commercial fonts and it is my understanding that `lucidabr` is the package needed to load them.  `lucimatx` is a package MiKTeX doesn't seem to know about.

Answer (score 1):

I searched a bit more and found [this](https://tug.org/pipermail/lucida/2009-December/000306.html) from which I extracted the following solution which seems to work for me:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lucidabr}
% \renewcommand{\rmdefault}{\sfdefault}   % <-- see edit below

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Test}
  123 and $123$ and $$123$$
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Of course, I don't know enough about the internals to know if this is a good idea.

**EDIT:** I was mistaken.  The important bit is not the line I marked above but that I didn't use the `professionalfonts` option.  As I said in one of the comments, this seems to be OK from how I understand the Beamer docs.

Comment: Unless `beamer` treats `lucidabr` as a special case, this would get you the text letters in math mode, but not Lucida Bright math symbols.